# How to get value from modified object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to get modified value of object? index.js is called before index2.js
**object.js**

```html
var object = {
  size:'5'
};

var setSize = function(size) {
  object.size = size;
}
  
exports.object = object;
exports.setSize = setSize;
```

**index.js**

```html
var obj = require('path/object');

obj.setSize('10');
console.log(obj.object.size); //--> 10
```

**index2.js**
I want the result to be 10.

```html
var obj = require('path/object');
console.log(obj.object.size); //--> 5
```

Comment: require `index.js` for side effects only and it will execute the code in `index.js`.

Comment: thanks! :))) got exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `node index.js` separately from `node index2.js`, there is no way for `index2.js` to "know" what happened in the last process of `index.js`. You have to apply all your actions in a single process run. As @Andrew Li stated in his comment, you would have to `require` `index.js` in your `index2.js`. Simply requiring it, will have it's code executed and the changes to `obj.object` will be saved in Nodes module caching mechanism.

```
var obj = require('path/object');
require('./index'); 
// code inside index.js gets executed, changing obj.size to '10'
// note that this will also log '10' in the console, since a console.log(obj.size)
// is part of your code in index.js


console.log(obj.object.size) //--> 10
```

If you need to have `index.js` and `index2.js` executed in different processes but still be able to access a coherent value of `obj`, you need to store that value somewhere outside of the process space, like in a database or in the filesystem.